# Rails scope where does not equal

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm writing a scope that should say select all calls where call_status = open and unit_id is not nil.  I'm really weak on Ruby and also new to Rails and am having a hard time expressing this right.

Here what I have:

```
scope :open_calls, where(:call_status => "open", :unit_id != nil).order("id ASC")
```

Should I be using a different operator to evaluate nil?

Comment: Yes. I don't know any other way of doing this than where("call_status = ? AND NOT unit_id IS NULL", "open"). There might be a better way?

Comment: Do not use scopes like this. Use this with lambdas, just in case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to tell ActiveRecord to build a NULL clause with a hash. But you can chain string-style and hash-style where clauses:

```
scope :open_calls, where(:call_status => "open").where("unit_id IS NOT NULL").order("id ASC")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was doing where chaining earlier and it worked, but was trying to get it all done in a single hash.  Appreciate your help, I'll stick to chaining for now.

Comment: With Rails 4 you can also use `where.not(unit_id: nil)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
scope :open_calls, where("call_status IS ? AND unit_id IS NOT ?", "open", nil).order("id ASC")
```

Note that the values `"open"` and `nil` are placed in an array and we use `?` to insert them. This helps prevent SQL injection bugs due to quoting / escaping etc and is strongly recommended. [See here for more.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)